# Logback maintain logs older than 7 days as a archive

Tags: java, logging, logback

In logback is there any way to maintain logs older then 7 days as a archive file.

means i want to maintain logs older then 7 days as a archive file.

at the end of day logs should be converted as a archive file no matter about size.(per day 1 zip file)

1.zip

2.zip

|

7.zip

using RollingAppender 1st day logs gets deleted once 8th day comes....

but i want to maintain all 7 days logs as a archive files ..is there any solution..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the `<rollingPolicy>` (`TimeBasedRollingPolicy`) to delete the files after 7 days, then you should just not specify `<maxHistory>7</maxHistory>` in your configuration.

You should just leave the `<maxHistory>` out; it's optional and if it's not there, then archived log files are not deleted. (You should also not specify a `totalSizeCap` either, unless you want log files to be deleted if the total size is over that cap)

See:
https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html

Comment: yes, it's working now...thanks.
and what will be default size logback takes if i don't specify in rollingPolicy for per day 1 zip file...?